# Return covariant type of specialized template class

Tags: c++, inheritance, covariance, crtp

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
template<typename T>
class GridMetric{
  virtual GridMetric* getNeighbors(T value) = 0;
};

template<size_t N, typename T, typename Derived>
class MatrixBase : public GridMetric<T>{
  virtual MatrixBase<N,T,Derived>* getNeighbors(T value){return nullptr;}
};

template<size_t N, typename T>
class MatrixND : public MatrixBase<N,T,MatrixND<N,T>>{
  virtual MatrixND<2,T>* getNeighbors(T value){ /* ... */}
};

template<typename T>
class MatrixND<2,T> : public MatrixBase<2,T,MatrixND<2,T>>{
  virtual MatrixND<2,T>* getNeighbors(T value){ /* ... */}
};

template<typename T>
class Vector : public GridMetric<T>{
  virtual MatrixND<2,T>* getNeighbors(T value){ /* ... */}
};
```

So my abstract class GridMetric has two derived classes, Vector and MatrixBase. My Matrix Base class has crtp style derived class MatrixND and there is a specialization of MatrixND with N=2.

Each class shall have a virtual function getNeighbors to return a MatrixND<2,T> pointer.

It all works fine, except the MatrixND class complains that MatrixND<2,T> is an invalid covariant return type:

```
error: invalid covariant return type for ‘MatrixND<2ul, T>* MatrixND<N, T>::getNeighbors(T&) [with long unsigned int N = 3ul; T = double]’
  virtual MatrixND<2,T>* getNeighbors(T& in){
```

My first question is why and how can I deal with that? Since MatrixND<2,T> inherits from MatrixBase!

My second question: Is it bad design, because I would always return raw pointers? I read the expression return new obj.. a lot, but also that this is apparently bad design. Are there other possibilities to achieve the same?

**Edit:** So, after some time, I realized, that the original plan wasn't going to work out and I found a much easier solution by templating the class, where I want to use those classes.

Anyway, the question stands, why the specialized MatrixND class can not be a covarient return type in the general MatrixND class. I didn't find anything saying it isn't allowed.

Comment: Typo? The return type in `Vector` is `MatrixND<2,T>*`? And there is an `N` in `MatrixND<2,T>`, which should be `2`.

Comment: Yes indeed, the N was a mistake. And yes, the plan was to return a pointer to a 2D matrix.

Comment: Then you should declare `MatrixND` before `Vector`.

Comment: You're right, I put it in the end, but it makes no difference in my code. I forward declared all classes to exclude such errors.

Comment: The general `MatrixND<N, T>` should return a `MatrixND<N, T> *`, not `MatrixND<2, T> *`.

Comment: Now it [does compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tjdytVy5VPCgKGnO).

Comment: @O'Neil But I want it to return a MatrixND<2,T>*. The question is, why it isn't allowed. I can return a non virtual type MatrixND<2,T> inside the general MatrixND<N,T> and I can return a MatrixND<2,T>* in the class Vector. So why is it a valid covariant return type in Vector but not in MatrixND<N,T>? :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `MatrixND<2,T>`, basic case, no need for an explanation.
- `Vector<T>` inherits from `GridMetric<T>`, so anything deriving from `GridMetric<T>` (including `MatrixND<2,T>` here) is fine.

But, the general form `MatrixND<N,T>` (`N` != 2) inherits from `MatrixBase<N,T,MatrixND<N,T>>` which redefines the virtual function as:

```
virtual MatrixBase<N,T,Derived>* getNeighbors(T value){return nullptr;}
```

which forces the return type of `MatrixND<N,T>` to now derive (at least) from `MatrixBase<N,T,MatrixND<N,T>>`.
Not from `GridMetric<T>` (as for `Vector<T>`) or `MatrixBase<2,T,MatrixND<2,T>>` (as for the specialization `MatrixND<2,T>`), but: `MatrixBase<N,T,MatrixND<N,T>>`, with (`N` != 2).

And why this is not a covariant return type? Because `MatrixND<2,T>` does not inherit from `MatrixBase<N,T,MatrixND<N,T>>` when `N` != 2.

Either remove the function redefinition within `MatrixBase<N,T,MatrixND<N,T>>` or change its return type to `GridMetric<T>`, and this will work (as `MatrixND<2,T>` inherits from `GridMetric<T>`).

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes total sense and works. For whatever reason I believed I need to carry the function through the hierarchy and that, if I not, the function becomes pure virtual again and thus the class abstract. I still need to look into, what is the better solution for my purpose, but that was already very helpful :)